# Wix Rollback Quiet Execution Custom Action not working

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I want to install and start `Redis` (for Windows) as part of our software package. The installation and start of the service is working correctly, but an error occurs during the installation, followed by a rollback and the service is not removed after the rollback.

Can anyone help me find out what I'm doing wrong here? Also, do I need separate removal commands too, or does rollback work for the uninstall too?

(The values like [#fil5E85DBB2FFC8A2CFA55EDCADD8376C1F] are the Id's generated with HeatDirectory for the redis-server.exe and its directory)

```
<!--Install Redis-->
<CustomAction Id="SetRedisInstall"
              Property="RedisInstall"
              Value="&quot;[#fil5E85DBB2FFC8A2CFA55EDCADD8376C1F]&quot; --service-install &quot;[dir13BD3F7531FC8E0F30BB51FAA1B1357F]redis.windows.conf&quot; --loglevel verbose" />
<CustomAction Id="RedisInstall"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no"/>
<CustomAction Id="SetRedisStart" Property="RedisStart" Value="&quot;[#fil5E85DBB2FFC8A2CFA55EDCADD8376C1F]&quot; --service-start" />
<CustomAction Id="RedisStart"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no"/>

<!--Rollback Redis-->
<CustomAction Id="SetRedisStop" Property="RedisStop" Value="&quot;[#fil5E85DBB2FFC8A2CFA55EDCADD8376C1F]&quot; --service-stop" />
<CustomAction Id="RedisStop"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="rollback"
              Return="ignore"
              Impersonate="no"/>
<CustomAction Id="SetRedisRemove" Property="RedisRemove" Value="&quot;[#fil5E85DBB2FFC8A2CFA55EDCADD8376C1F]&quot; --service-uninstall" />
<CustomAction Id="RedisRemove"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="ignore"
              Return="asyncWait"
              Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <!--Install Redis-->
  <Custom Action="RedisInstall" Before="InstallFinalize">Not Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetRedisInstall" Before="RedisInstall">Not Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="RedisStart" After="RedisInstall">Not Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetRedisStart" Before="RedisStart">Not Installed</Custom>
  <!--Rollback Redis-->
  <Custom Action="SetRedisStop" Before="RedisStop"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="RedisStop" Before="RedisStart"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="RedisRemove" Before="RedisInstall"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetRedisRemove" Before="RedisRemove"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

**Edit** I have the component

```
<Feature Id="Redis" Title="Redis" Level="1" >
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="RedisWxs"/>
</Feature>
```

And the service part now too:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="siRedisService" Description="Redis Service" DisplayName="Redis" Arguments="&quot;[dir13BD3F7531FC8E0F30BB51FAA1B1357F]redis.windows.conf&quot;" ErrorControl="normal" Name="Redis" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Account="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"/>
<ServiceControl Id="scRedisService" Name="Redis" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Wait="yes" />
```

How can I add the service to the existing component?

**Edit 2**

I have disabled automatc harvesting and edited the output file, so that fixes the reference problem. I still have the problem that the Redis service can't start. However, when I just copy paste the path (incl config file) in cmd, it works perfectly fine...

This is the code

```
        <Component Id="cmp911C50BAA696496834114926A958787D" Guid="*">
            <File Id="fil5E85DBB2FFC8A2CFA55EDCADD8376C1F" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RedisPath)\redis-server.exe" />
            <ServiceInstall Id="siRedisService" DisplayName="Redis" Arguments="--service-run redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose" ErrorControl="normal" Name="Redis" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Account="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"/>
            <ServiceControl Id="scRedisService" Name="Redis" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Wait="yes" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmpFC38C2953561FABFFCF29CCEC52692E1" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filF5607FB03CD4B203C699DA14D17FF53B" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RedisPath)\redis.windows.conf" />
        </Component>
```

**Edit 3 - working solution**

There was a permission problem, this is how I fixed it:

```
        <Component Id="cmp911C50BAA696496834114926A958787D" Guid="*">
            <File Id="fil5E85DBB2FFC8A2CFA55EDCADD8376C1F" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RedisPath)\redis-server.exe" />
            <CreateFolder Directory="dir13BD3F7531FC8E0F30BB51FAA1B1357F">
              <util:PermissionEx User="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE" GenericAll="yes" />
            </CreateFolder>
            <ServiceInstall Id="siRedisService" DisplayName="Redis" Arguments="--service-run &quot;[#filF5607FB03CD4B203C699DA14D17FF53B]&quot;" ErrorControl="normal" Name="Redis" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Account="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE"/>
            <ServiceControl Id="scRedisService" Name="Redis" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Wait="yes" />
        </Component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sure is a lot of custom actions.  I would get rid of them.  Here's how I roll:

```
<Component Id="redacted" Guid="redacted">
  <File Id="redacted" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\redis-server.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
  <ServiceInstall Id="siRedisService" Description="Redis Service" DisplayName="Redis" Arguments="--service-run redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose" ErrorControl="normal" Name="Redis" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Account="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"/>
  <ServiceControl Id="scRedisService" Name="Redis" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Wait="yes" />
</Component>
<Component Id="redacted" Guid="redacted">
  <File Id="redacted" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\redis.windows.conf" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

I've said it many times in the past... a service is a service is a service.  Anything other then ServiceInstall and ServiceControl and the occasional Registry entry is a form of Self Registration antipattern madness.  Services can be written in different languages and hosted by different runtimes but their interaction with the service control manager APIs are all the same and MSI can handle it natively once you work out those details.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It seems to install, stop and remove the service correctly, but there is a problem starting it. The files are already placed by a heat harvested wxs file, can I refer to that existing component and add the service?

Comment: I'm also against any kind of build time dynamic authoring of installers.  Harvest, dependency scanning, dynamic file linking and so on.  It's rarely reliable or a net gain.  Wxs is code... just write it as such.

Comment: OK, will do that. Harvesting was already disabled now. I see no difference in Services between this installed service and that of Redis itself. In cmd it works perfectly too, but it can't start as a service...

Comment: I pulled that snippet from production code so it should work.  Is it logging anything?  One difference between a console app and a service is working directory.  Services start from System32. But that shouldn't be a problem here since I know this works.

Comment: That's just a generic error from the service control manager.  Does redis ever log anything?  You could try using a [#filekey] for the config file argument to the service.

Comment: I see no logs. I've tried the filekey too, this is the path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\X\Y\redis-2.8.12\redis-server.exe" --service-run "C:\Program Files (x86)\X\Y\redis-2.8.12\redis.windows.conf" --loglevel verbose. Same error though.

Comment: so what's your .conf file look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60258/discussion-between-aaron-and-christopher-painter).